# No module named base while running python manage.py --settings=[mysettings]

Tags: python, django

While running command - `python manage.py test --settings=todobackend.settings.test`
 from terminal inside virtualenv I get the error `ImportError: No module named base`

I'm running python 2.7
and Django 1.9.0

**Hierarchy**

```
todobackend
    settings
        base.py
        test.py
manage.py
```

**test.py**

```
from base import *
import os
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('MYSQL_DATABASE', 'todobackend'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('MYSQL_USER', 'todo'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('MYSQL_PASSWORD', 'password'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('MYSQL_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'PORT': os.environ.get('MYSQL_PORT', '3306')
    }
}
```

**base.py**

```
"""
Django settings for todobackend project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.11.20.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'todos'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'todobackend.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'todobackend.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# CORS Settings
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

**manage.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE",
                          "todobackend.settings.base")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError:
        # The above import may fail for some other reason. Ensure that the
        # issue is really that Django is missing to avoid masking other
        # exceptions on Python 2.
        try:
            import django
        except ImportError:
            raise ImportError(
                "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
                "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
                "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
            )
        raise
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You settings folder is not a Python package, you must add a file named `__init__.py` to that folder.

Comment: There is `__init__.py` just outside `settings` folder. Shall I move this empty file inside settings folder?

Comment: You should create another inside settings folder I can't tell you to move that one you already have cuz can create another problem.

Comment: Sure. I did that i.e. created an empty `__init__.py` file and ran the same command. It says now, `ImportError: No module named d`

Comment: Well, I can tell you already has tackled the original problem, now you have another problem with some module called `d` that can't be found.  I would suggest writing another question about this new problem.

Comment: I don't have module named  `d`. You have all the relevant code. I didn't change anything per se of code since posting. And I believe idea is to make the code running and actually help here. 

In case you have to logically debate. I have few questions. How would I know your solution fixes my problem entirely? What if you posted half of it?

Comment: @kushalvm, Well I can't be sure my answer is enough to get your code running, But I'm sure the error you post originally is not there anymore.  And yes the idea is to help, but not only help you but all user searching for some answer. The 
 the problem you have now might also be a problem for others too, and the title of this question might be misleading about this new error, in fact, might have nothing to do with it. So, the need for another question is for clarity on what is the actual problem and what would be the solution for that particular problem.

Comment: @kushalvm You should read this answer too about doing more than one question in the same post. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/371617/2890724

Comment: I guess. This is something else now.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have 'base' in your INSTALLED_APPS which is what Django looks for when you just import base in your test.py file.
On top of this, the later versions of Python seem to really prefer the full import path rather than relative ones and can throw an error if this is not used.

**To fix this, just add:**

```
//test.py
from todobackend.settings.base import *
```

I hope this helps!